# Prove that if A is invertible then A is the change of basis matrix for some 2 basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If T is a vector space (dim n), B a basis of T and $$ A ∈ k^{n×n} $$ a matrix invertible. I need to prove that there are basis B1 and B2 such that: (i) A is the change of basis matrix from B1 to B (ii) A is the change of basis matrix from B to B2.

I was thinking that if A is invertible, then I could use something with the composition of $A ° A^{-1}$ and work with that. On the other hand, I though that maybe I could use something like $$ (g  o  f)_{b1b3} = (g)_{b2b3}. (f)_{b1b2} $$
(Considering b1= B, b3= B1, and b2=...)
To be honest, those are some ideas but I don't feel like they are useful in this case. I'd appreciate some help

Comment: If $A$ is invertible, what do you know about the images and preimages of basis vectors under $A$?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). And use "invertible" for a matrix, and not reversible.

Comment: @blargoner I'm trying to find the relation among those concepts, but I'm not sure how to use it here

Comment: @Jean For example if vectors $v_1,\ldots,v_k$ span the vector space, what can you say about $Av_1,\ldots,Av_k$? What if instead the vectors are linearly independent? What does that tell you about bases?